# Image not resizing using media queries past 480px

Tags: css, media-queries, image-resizing

I'm currently trying to optimize a main image on a page for all screen sizes. For some reason, I cannot get it to resize after 480px. The code inside the query is correct. Just to check, I've inputted the same exact code into the tablet sized query, and I get the proper resize. When I change the attributes for screen size inside the query to 480px, I get nothing.

The image starts at 600px, then first resizes fine to 400px. However after that, it will not resize anymore. I want it to be 200px wide.

Here is what I have in the CSS - as you can see it's practically identical to the query above it for the tablet:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------
    Small Desktop/Tablet (2x4 boxes) 
    --------------------------------------------------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px), only screen and (max-device-width: 959px) {

#imageWrap{
height:400px;
width:400px;
}

    #imageWrap img{
height:400px;
width:400px;
}

}
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
Smartphone (1x8 boxes)
--------------------------------------------------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

#imageWrap{
height:200px;
width:200px;
}

#imageWrap img{
height:200px;
width:200px;
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have one too many `}` in your first code block, which might be disabling the second (something the CSS validator would pick up).

Comment: Thanks a million! I knew this involved a silly error somewhere. I just needed a second set of eyes.